# SQL Server 2008 : sum a Computed Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Trying to write a query that will pull certain information for a program that will be using it in the future...I have all needed columns but noticed something a little wonky.

My query:

```
SELECT    
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), oe_hdr.order_date, 110) AS 'order_date', 
   oe_hdr.order_no, anspin_view_booked_orders_ship_to_rep.salesrep_name, 
   oe_hdr.location_id, oe_hdr.taker, ship2_name, 
   anspin_view_booked_orders_ship_to_rep.supplier_id,
   ((qty_ordered - qty_canceled) * (unit_price_home / pricing_unit_size)) AS "Order Total"
FROM 
   oe_hdr
INNER JOIN
   anspin_view_booked_orders_ship_to_rep ON oe_hdr.order_no = anspin_view_booked_orders_ship_to_rep.order_no
WHERE 
   oe_hdr.order_date BETWEEN '06/01/2014 00:00:00' AND '6/30/2014 23:59:59'
ORDER BY 
   oe_hdr.order_date
```

Everything looks perfect EXCEPT the fact that it'll show line items for each order number, and not the actual total for that order_no.  I created the order total column using a computed column, but is there any way to show the sum of each order?

Here is an example of what is returned (with my freetyped headers just for formatting sake):

```
Date        OrderNo  Name   ID  x   x   Supp    Order Total
06-02-2014  1032490 name    30  x   x   100375  69.200000000000
06-02-2014  1032490 name    30  x   x   100375  47.780000000000
06-02-2014  1032490 name    30  x   x   100375  152.560000000000
06-02-2014  1032490 name    30  x   x   100375  45.900000000000
```

Desired Results (for each and every order, this being just one):

```
Date        OrderNo  Name   ID  x   x   Supp    Order Total
06-02-2014  1032490 name    30  x   x   100375  315.44
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that when I posted.  I'm done editing now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `group by`.  Here is correct syntax (I think):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), oh.order_date,110) as order_date,
       oh.order_no, bosr.salesrep_name,
       oh.location_id, oh.taker, ship2_name,
       bosr.supplier_id,
       SUM((qty_ordered-qty_canceled)*(unit_price_home / pricing_unit_size)) as "Order Total"
from oe_hdr oh inner join
     anspin_view_booked_orders_ship_to_rep bosr
     on oh.order_no = bosr.order_no
where oh.order_date >= '2014-06-01' and
      oh.order_date < '2014-07-01'
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), oh.order_date, 110), 
         oh.order_no, bosr.salesrep_name,
         oh.location_id, oh.taker, ship2_name,
         bosr.supplier_id
order by order_date;
```

Here are the changes:

- The most important one is the addition of the `group by` clause and `sum()` expression.
- Removed the table alias from the `order by` and replaced with the column alias.
- Removed the single quotes from the column alias.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Use double quotes or square braces for aliases, when you need to.
- Changed the date constants to ISO standard formats
- Changed the `between` to two comparisons.  In general, it is best to avoid `between` on `datetime` values.  In your case, this prevents a problem when an order is placed half a second before midnight.

Note:  I included all `select`ed columns in the `group by`.  I do not know if these will create multiple columns per order on a given day.  If so, just include the columns that you really need in the `select` and `group by`.